# How can I custom order Drupal Views' groups and include custom HTML for each group?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have 6 custom content types and a View that shows the 6 types and groups results by node type.

Example: the custom content types are Computers, Cars, Food, etc. The view groups nodes by those types:

```
[exposed filters here]

Computers
 - HP P6500
 - Leveno HQ3112

Cars
 - Ford F150
 - GM Silverado

Food
 - Apple
 - Banana
```

How can sort the groups in an arbitrary way? I.e. Food, Cars, Computers. Also, how can I specify a custom title for each group and custom HTML? I want to have a picture next to each group title, custom colors on the title, etc. I tried accomplishing this with the viewfield, views_field_view, and viewreference modules and making separate subviews for each content type, and a master view to show them all, but I was having problems with the exposed filters and pagination working. I might be going about this the wrong way. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Views 3.x with Drupal 7, so I'm not certain this is completely applicable.  But I wanted to mention it as I faced the exact same issue (sorting portion of your question).

For sorting the groups in an arbitrary way, the quickest solution I came up was using the Global: PHP sort (in the Views UI).  If the Food, Cars, and Computers were Content Types, then something like this should work...

```php
switch ($row1->type) {
  case 'food':
    return -1;
    break;
  case 'computers':
    return 1;
    break;
  case 'cars':
    if ($row2->type == 'computers') {
      return -1;
    }
    elseif ($row2->type == 'food') {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      return 0;
    }
    break;
  default:
    return 0;
  break;
}
```

I also used [Views Grouping Row Limit](http://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping) module, which gave more control over the groups.
Using that module, you can modify the group output via template and with CSS (unique ID's for the group), which would allow you to add an image for that Group name.

For renaming a group title, you could use jQuery, but I ended up using one of the views hooks, hook_views_post_render:

```php
function MODULE_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache) {
  $output = str_replace('<h3>Original Title</h3>', '<h3>' . t('New Title') . '</h3>', $output);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For complete control over your view output I suggest you try to take a look at the views templates that are in the modules/views/theme folder. Don't edit these directly but copy them to your theme folder and edit them there. (You need to clear the cache so drupal picks up your copies).

To find out which template you should edit, a very nice tool is http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer.

For smaller changes it can be easier to use theme hooks instead, but if you want to do a lot of changes it can be smart to work directly on the templates.